# how to have my bootstrap modal stay in place and not disappear after my ajax forms submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Note: I'm on a Rails 2 app (yep it's old) and Bootstrap 4.4

So I have a bootstrap modal that contains a working remote_form_for ajax form on it. When I submit my form, the div element on my page I am targeting reloads it's content....yea...this is what I want. HOWEVER, the modal disappears and leaves the modals background ...

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

...on the page. How do I...

1. have the modal stay in place and not disappear after my ajax forms submission?

OR

2. run a JavaScript (jquery or prototype) on ajax success that will remove the  `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`

Here is the modal forms first line just so you can see how I have it set up so far

```
<% remote_form_for(:attendance, :html=>{:id=>"modalForm_#{sched.current.id}"}, :url => {:action => "attendance",:id => sched.current.id} ,:update =>"Assignment_#{sched.current.id}") do |g|%>
... form guts here
<%= g.submit "Update" %>
```

Any help is appreciated. I've been banging my head for a week on this.

Comment: Missing some crucial details. It could be a click listener or the response of the form. It's not something Rails itself is doing, though.

Comment: @JoshBrody Hmm, what else should I post in my question (trying not to be overwhelming with my question code block)?

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did to solve #2 (#1 is still unsolved) ...

```
<% remote_form_for(:attendance, :html=>{:onsubmit => "jQuery('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut(200, function(){jQuery(this).remove();});" ,:id=>"modalForm_#{assignment.id}"}, ,:url => {:action => "doattendance",:id => assignment.id} ,:update =>"Assignment_#{assignment.id}") do |g|%>
```

Notice the jQuery incantation inside the :html=>